# Python multithreaded, Sleep / Wait not working

Tags: python, multithreading, wait, sleep

Been turning my python OpenCV code into multi-threaded tonight and have come completely stuck.

As far as I'm aware I must be the only example on the internet where time.sleep and event.wait do not work.

I have 3 threads, first thread finds boxes, the second thread figures out if it's a good time to make an action and the final thread uses both of these threads to act on this information.

```
def click_boxes():
global list_of_boxes
global player_obj
if (player_obj.status == "idle"):
    for box in list_of_boxes:
        if box.status == 'fallen':
            
            print(time.time())
            time.sleep(1.0)
            print("???? , " + str(time.time()))
            return None
```

results in sleep or wait not blocking / having no function at all.

If I '.join()' this final click_boxes thread that I wish to block, I get a functional sleep/wait BUT it blocks the entire script so I lose all benefit of multi-threading.

```
click_boxes_t = threading.Thread(target=click_boxes, args=())
click_boxes_t.start()
click_boxes_t.join()
```

This might sound stupid but I haven't found an answer on the internet. When wait() and sleep() are not working in a multi-threaded scenario. Why not? what's the solution?

Comment: It's not clear from the question what behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're using `globals`, which does not make much sense with threading. Nor is having a `return` in a loop. Really unclear what you're trying to achieve. Share some more code perhaps?

Comment: does your `time.time()` statements print anything? (is this part of the code reached at all?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. time returns 100.1, 100.2, 100.3... for a 1 second delay.

I am using return as this is not a loop but a iterative structure. I don't want this thread to carry on in the for preceeding for statements, hence the return None.

I'm not willing to share all of my code as it's application is rather sensitive.

Comment: Where is the working of your other 2 threads?

Comment: What makes you think that `time.sleep(1.0)` does not work? What does the program actually print out when you run it? And, what makes you think that `event.wait()` does not work? There is no such method call in your example!! You will get better help, and you will get it sooner if you show the code, tell us what you expected it to do, and tell us what it actually did instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using non-blocking 'if time now > time set + time to wait'